# Swagger Sails JS

Tags: sails.js, swagger, swagger-ui

Any idea of how to integrate **swagger**, swagger-ui with a **sails js** project?

Where can i found information about it, or about another way to comment an api generated with sails?

Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, let me see your project. Thanks!

Comment: Strongloop gives this out-of-the-box

Answer (score 34):

I was searching for a solution for this a little over a week ago, but I found the information scattered a bit. Here's how I integrated swagger and swagger-ui with my sails 0.11.x project.

## 1. Install sails-swagger

```
npm install --save sails-swagger
```

This provides a hook that will dynamically generate the swagger document. Unfortunately, it's only compatible with sails 0.12.x (which is an rc at the time of this post). So, to get it working with 0.11.x you have to extend SwaggerController and overwrite the hook's name in config/installedHooks.js ([issue reference](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger/issues/3#issuecomment-149663772))

#### api/controllers/SwaggerController.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * This is a temp fix while one sails 11.x
 * @see https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger/issues/3
 */
var _ = require('lodash');
var _super = require('sails-swagger/dist/api/controllers/SwaggerController');

_.merge(exports, _super);
_.merge(exports, {
  _config: {
    actions: false,
    shortcuts: false,
    rest: false
  }
});
```

#### config/installedHooks.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * This is a temp fix while one sails 11.x
 * @see https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger/issues/3
 */
module.exports.installedHooks = {
  'sails-swagger': {
    'name': 'swagger'
  }
};
```

Lastly, provide the hook's configuration per the docs

#### config/swagger.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports.swagger = {
  /**
   * require() the package.json file for your Sails app.
   */
  pkg: require('../package')
};
```

## 2. Install swagger-ui

```
npm install --save-dev swagger-ui@2
```

There are a few ways to handle this. You can use the vanilla swagger-ui module and add everything in its `dist` to your build process. But I chose to copy it into my project because I intend to customize the interface a bit.

```
mkdir assets/docs
cp -r node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/* assets/docs/
```

> NOTE (3/26/2017): swagger-ui v3.x has been re-built using React (yay!), but easily integrating it with sails is not obvious at the moment.

## 3. Configure swagger-ui

Lastly, you need to point swagger-ui to your dynamically generated swagger doc. The default route for the swagger doc is [`/swagger/doc`](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger/blob/master/api/hooks/swagger/index.js#L21), so you can set it explicitly in the swagger-ui configuration.

#### assets/docs/index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var url = '/swagger/doc';

      // Pre load translate...
      if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
        window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
      }
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        url: url,
        // ...removed for brevity
</script>
```

## 4. Profit

Now you can navigate to `/docs` in your browser and see your beautiful documentation.

[image: sails-swagger-ui]

Comment: @Vanuan: You can disable default settings in `blueprints.js` if not using them. That will remove all of it from swagger doc as well

Comment: this doesn't work if you installed with the --no-frontend option

Comment: node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/ no longer contains index.html. There are only 4 files.

Comment: @jankigadhiya thanks for the heads up! I've added a note to limit the swagger-ui install to 2.x.

Comment: if your project was generated with *--no-frontend* option then you have to copy `node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/` to `.tmp/public/docs` (using grunt task for example)

Comment: how to run this on sails v1.0?

Comment: how i can configure this steps for sails v1.0 ?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution using [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui). I create a folder called **docs** in **assets** sails folder, put the **swagger-ui** content in there, and edit the **swagger.json** file. Then, I did sails lift. The docs is now available in http://ip_address:1337/docs. I'm using sails v- 0.11.0

Comment: Maybe just a bit more info - the easiest is to download the zip and put the /dist folder contents wherever you want the swagger ui to live. After that the only thing you have to change is the url - the sails-swagger package generates the swagger file at '/swagger/doc'. Afterwards this works great.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of generating the documentation automatically, you can check out this library as I think it better solves the problem and simply generates the swagger.json file automatically from your controllers and routes.

```
npm install sails-hook-swagger-generator --save
```

then simply `sails lift` and check the **swagger** folder, which you must have created before running `sails lift`

### Updates

It now has support OAS 3.0 and also better documentation for actions and action2s

for more about the configuration, you can view the repo [here](https://github.com/theo4u/sails-hook-swagger-generator)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: how can be integrate swagger ui to view that json in a browser on some route?

Comment: oh you can go through this https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#download-33 and use the JSON generated as the url path @Pavan

Comment: BTW, Theo is the author of the linked sails hook.

Comment: @TheophilusOmoregbee where can i see the swagger? when i get up this http://ip_address:1337/docs. i did not nothing

Comment: @x-rw for now the library does not support viewing generated swagger Json doc, there’s an issue to follow up with that here: https://github.com/theoomoregbee/sails-hook-swagger-generator/issues/28 but you can use configure it to use swagger doc UI

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
$ npm install sails-swagger --save
```

Configuration

```
    // config/swagger.js
module.exports.swagger = {
  /**
   * require() the package.json file for your Sails app.
   */
  pkg: require('../package'),
  ui: {
    url: 'http://swagger.balderdash.io'
  }
};
```

After installing and configuring swagger, you can find the docs output on the `/swagger/doc` route.

Answer (score 0):

install: `npm i @logisticinfotech/sails-hook-actions2-swagger`
and open in your browser `http://localhost:1337/swagger`.

only that, cool.