# Swagger Sails JS rendered as JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, swagger, swagger-ui

Trying to get a swagger document, I followed exactly as suggested by Nitheesh K P in the solution. I am able to get the swagger output when I access the url /swagger/doc but it looks like a REST response. It lacks the nice view that I was expecting, like one in http://swagger.balderdash.io.

In other words, I have followed: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-swagger and get REST response rather than swagger document.

Please help me figure out what am I missing? Some basic configurations in Sails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem that either Sails or the Swagger hook you are referencing to, contain [Swagger UI](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/). You should install and configure Swagger UI in a separate process - [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560472/3990817) for more details.

Comment: Tried, but did not work. The result is still in JSON REST format, no UI

Comment: The content of `/swagger/doc` _should_ be in JSON format. The UI should be installed on a different endpoint (if you followed step (2) of the SO answer linked above, it should be at `/docs`).